# Execute gulp4 task on cordova hook

Tags: cordova, gulp-4, cordova-hooks

Recently I upgraded to nodejs 12, that required me to upgrade to gulp4. The upgrade was a must so I cannot downgrade.

Now, my cordova hook does not execute the gulp task.

Previously I executed it as:

```
gulp.start('build');
```

Now, `gulp.start` is no longer included in gulp4, `gulp.series`, `gulp.parallel`, `gulp.task` do not work either...

**How can I call my task from my hook?**

My hook file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

function hook() {
    process.stdout.write('Running gulp build task');

    require('../gulpfile.js');
    //interaction
    gulp.start('build');
}

module.exports = hook;
```

The gulp task is defined in gulpfile.js and is defined as:

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series(['moveBrandingFiles', 'webpack-task', 'sass', 'index']));
```

If I manually execute `gulp build` it will work.

Comment: Did you try `gulp.series(hook0`  no qotes around the function name - they are not needed.

Comment: Cordova has the hook and calls the gulp process... The build task is defined as: `gulp.task('build', gulp.series(['moveBrandingFiles', 'webpack-task', 'sass', 'index']));`

Did you mean to move the gulp.series into a function and call the function?

The function would be in a gulpfile.js and the hook is in a nodejs file...  How could I do that?